# New activity for each item in list view

Tags: android

For example there is 50 items in my list view . Items of list view consist of questions and when user clicks the item it goes to next activity and shows the answer . SO how can i do this . please suggest me any idea that may help

Comment: Did you do any thing ? show your effort first

Comment: `Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class); intent.putExtra("selectedItemId", selectedItemId); startActivity(intent);`.

Comment: Put question data to intent and pass it to your QuestionActivity, in that activity, use getIntent().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In  FirstActivity.java

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    Intent intents = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                    intents.putExtra("questionId", questionID);//select question id from array using arry postion
                    startActivity(intents);

                }

                );
            }
```

In SecondActivity.java

```
int questionId=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("questionId");
```

Display answer base on selected question ID.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the list clickable, apply `setOnItemClickListener`.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class); 
            startActivity(intent);

        });
```

Comment: yes this helps a lot but as i mentioned list view contains 50 questions and its so time consuming that i have to create 50 activity for each answer of a question .